# Check Drives Before Installation: Is Badblocks Good Enough?

Tags: testing, hard-drive, bad-blocks

I wanted to know what people do to test drives before installing them in a RAID.  I saw [badblocks](http://linux.die.net/man/8/badblocks).  Would write-mode, *prior to installing the filesystem* be sufficient in your minds?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In mine surely will. On modern drives with all those SMARTs even simply zeroing it would be enough to see whether drive's healthy or not.